# Replacing JSON values with CSS in React

Tags: json, reactjs

I'll try to explain this the best I can. There is a JSON result which separates every paragraph of the text and marks them with 0 or 1 (or even 0.3 etc). The Stringified results on the frontend shows those numbers too. Is there a way to replace these and apply CSS styles based on the value (0, 0.1, or 1)?

the JSON:

```
"content": [
  [0.0, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", []],
  [0.0, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", []],
  [1, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", []],
];
```

Comment: `array::map` and add an inline `style` or `className` prop. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to do this. Easiest being the switch statement, given several cases.
I assume you are mapping the content array to div elements.

```
content.map(item => {
  let styles;
  switch (item[0]){
    case "0.0":
      styles = {color: "red"};
      break;
    case "0.1":
      styles = {color: "green"};
      break;
    case "1":
      styles = {color: "blue"};
      break;
    default:
      styles = {color: "black"};
  }
  return <div style={styles}>{item[1]}</div>

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I have updated my question and added some info!

Answer (score 0):

The React way to do this is using `array.map()`:

```js
content.map((element) => {
  return (
    <div style={{cssProperty: element[0]}}>
      {element[1]}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I have updated my question and added some info!